# Ajax same origin policy and Jquery $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

We know that Ajax requests can only be made to resources on the same server where we are running our application, which is known as the same origin policy.
But in the JQuery ajax method $.getJSON for example, we are able to pass in any url even if it does not involve our own server. Isnt this a violation of the no cross domain ajax requests policy ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getJSON` uses the [JSONP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Instead of making an XmlHTTPRequest, which cannot cross domains, it makes a `<script>` tag pointing to a URL in a different domain.
The URL is assumed to return a script that calls the specified callback function with the relevant data.

Comment: Basiclly it wrapps the json response in a return function.

Comment: More importantly, it requires that you fully trust the target URL. If you don't, you are providing them the opportunity to run code on your site, which could be abused to attack either the site or the user.